# service runs on xp but on win 7 its not running (related to c#)

Tags: c#, windows

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController("MyServiceName");

if ((service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) ||

    (service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))

    service.Start();

else    service.Stop();
```

its working on xp 32 bit but not working on win 7.ti throws a exception access denied.
is there any solution to this.plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your C# program has to run with the same credentials as the service you are trying to start, otherwise you will need elevation due to [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) under Windows 7 - there is a sample for that [here](http://www.aneef.net/2009/06/29/request-uac-elevation-for-net-application-managed-code/).